# How to increase local storage memory in chromium?

Tags: javascript, chromium, chromium-embedded

I already searched a lot but did not found anything helpful,

I'm looking for a way to increase the local storage memory in chromium.

Anything on it would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried passing  `--unlimited-storage` as an argument to Chromium when starting it? This flag should be used for testing only

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it's limited and can't be changed. This is a [design decision made by Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58985), with the reason being that it doesn't scale well. With that being said there are few other solutions you can use, check out this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria) about saving data in the browser.

When someone asked the Chromium team members to increase the size, this is what one of them responded:

> We don't want people to store large amounts of information in
> LocalStorage.  The API can block a page (and any other pages in your
> same renderer process) while it loads LocalStorage into memory because
> it's a synchronous API.  Honestly, we'd just plain not support it if
> we could, but too many developers/sites rely on it.  So this is the
> compromise.
>
> But clearly we don't want you loading hundreds of megs into memory and
> thus blocking everything in the web browser for extended periods of
> time.
>
> IndexedDB is a bit easier than WebSQLDatabase and will be ready for
> prime time before long.  WebSQLDatabase isn't *that* complicated.
> FileSystem is really the right place to store big files (which is what
> it sounds like you're doing) and is available in Chrome 9.  I suggest
> you look at these alternatives.
>
> I'm tempted to mark this as a WontFix...
>
> But, [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) might be a good solution for you.